# SqLite syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fallowing  video tutorials about `SqlLite` .But I think I missed out something I am getting this exception

> E/SQLiteLog(1888): (1) near "TABLEusers": syntax error

.I  have double checked the query .Can you please help

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+DB_TABLE+"("
                                      + KEY_ROWID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_NAME+"TEXT NOT NULL,"
                                      +KEY_PASS +"TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need spaces between keywords and identifiers, such as `TABLE` and `DB_TABLE` and column names and their types:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE+"("
                                      + KEY_ROWID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                                      +KEY_PASS +" TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add space between `column name` and `column type` in your **CREATE TABLE** Query. correct your query with below:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE+"( "
                                  + KEY_ROWID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                  +KEY_PASS +" TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed out space between `TABLE` keyword and table name

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE+"("
                                      + KEY_ROWID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                                      +KEY_PASS +" TEXT NOT NULL);");
```